# How to build older version of glibc?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling, glibc

I am building gcc-8.1.0 cross-compiler for arm, for Ubuntu Xenial 16.04. 
That package exists as a debian package but only for Ubuntu 18.04 bionic which is why I am building it. 
But there is a problem - namely, gcc-8.1.0 exists as a package for x86_64 system for Ubuntu 16.04 (for native architecture). It downloads all the dependencies, among which glibc-2.23. 
When I want to build gcc cross-compiler for **arm** architecture according to the instructions given here: http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/
at step 6 when making standard C library glibc fails to be build because of an error `` /tmp/ccs9D1VT.s: Error: `loc1@GLIBC_2.17' can't be versioned to common symbol 'loc1' ``.
I tried with older versions of gcc (4.9.3 & 5.4.0) in the previous steps according to manual given in the link, but seems that glibc has this bug.

So, I am wondering - if that's the bug in glibc-2.23 how is it being built at all? 
Since I have it installed with my debian package for x86_64 Ubuntu Xenial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to backport this upstream commit:

> ```
> commit 388b4f1a02f3a801965028bbfcd48d905638b797
> Author: H.J. Lu <hjl.tools@gmail.com>
> Date:   Fri Jun 23 14:38:46 2017 -0700
> ```
>
> ### [Avoid .symver on common symbols [BZ #21666]](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=388b4f1a02f3a801965028bbfcd48d905638b797)
>
> The .symver directive on common symbol just creates a new common symbol, not an alias and the newer assembler with the bug fix for
>
> https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21661
>
> will issue an error.  Before the fix, we got […]

This commit is [already included on the `release/2.23/master` branch](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=bc566388d68eb631a6ff0408d57a78d0a2781025), so you could just that.